# FCM for VoIP calls

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, voip

I was playing with FCM and i noticed that even without restrictions it can take from couple of seconds to 1min or so to receive a push notification.
This is acceptable for most uses.

Then i was thinking about those popular VOIP hybrids like WhatsApp etc, relying on FCM for VOIP calls is fine if the push comes almost immediately, after 40 sec or 1 min not so much. Imagine ringing someone and that someone only gets notified after 1min when FCM is finally delivered.

A good workaround that i see on those apps are that some maintains a TCP Connection, but that's not so effective for Voip if your vendor decide to kill the app to squeeze some battery or even when your phone is dozing and restricting network.

I heard iPhone has some sort of Voip push, is there something similar for android, how to handle this ?

Comment: Why not perform a VoIP call?

Comment: A VoIP call with it's respective Signaling Protocols is not enough to wake a android phone from doze mode (Unless you keep screen on or programmatically disable doze). You need to be able to keep a socket which doze restricts network use unless you whitelist app and avoid your vendor's task killer from affecting your app or you can rely on FCM and flag a notification as high priority which will bypass restrictions and wake your phone.